# Text file recovery on corrupted file system of Flashdrive

Tags: c++, filesystems, data-recovery, fat32

I am able to read raw data of the corrupted file system of USB drive.
Is there any simple way for me to recover only text and docx files by using these raw data? (Programming Language: C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to do it, but it won't be simple.

First of all you will need to parse the file system (i assume it's fat32 from the tags). In fact you will need to parse `File Allocation Table` (if it's corrupted and mirror copy of `FAT` was enabled on your drive, then you can try with it). Depending on corruption you it might be possible to extract some files. Read [this article](https://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html) for more info about FAT32 structure and you can use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463080.aspx) Microsoft specification as more strict guide. Good approach to understand the filesystem is to make some small usb or logical drive with sample file and parse it manually using some hex editor (free `wxHexEditor` or proprietary `WinHex` for example).

You can try to search sequences of `ASCII` characters in your Hex image, but then you will need to sort them manually.

As for docx, this format internally is a collection of XML files and resources, compressed in zip. So it will be way to complicated task to restore it from raw hex image

Comment: Hi @trvecvlt, thanks for your solution. just a bit curious at "parse File allocation table" could you briefly explain more? also how does the sequences of ASCII characters works in order to recover the data

Comment: @jodylan, there are 2 links in my answer, you should check them first and if some more specific details are unclear for, you can ask about them here. The whole topic is to big for Q and A format.

Comment: @jodylan, and about `ASCII` characters, for raw text files you can just loop through you image and check if hex values are inside `ASCII` range and there is a sequence of them longer than some value. It will extract all text data(incl. `ASCII` file names) from your image image in unsorted order. But it's simple and it could be usefull if you have only few text files on your drive.

Comment: just wondering how do I gonna extract the file from this hex value. would mind share some sample??

Comment: @jodylan, parse boot record -> find root cluster -> parse child dirs and files recursively -> find your file -> extract the data following the cluster chains. 
You can try with this util: http://gitorious.org/unix-stuff/fat-util as example and check this link as more hands-on description http://wiki.osdev.org/FAT

Comment: I would like say many thanks to you for your guidance on this topic. Appreciate your time and information. Without these information it will be very difficult for me. Currently trying to code it with C++.